# How to load script in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to load axios in chromium using puppeteer, the code is as follows:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://httpbin.org/get')
  await page.evaluate(async () => {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src','https://unpkg.com/axios@0.21.0/dist/axios.min.js');
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    var r = await axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
    console.log(r)
  })
})()
```

But when I try to execute `axios.get` it returns `Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: axios is not defined`. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [page.addScriptTag](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions) for this:

```
await page.goto('https://example.com');

await page.addScriptTag({ url: 'https://unpkg.com/axios@0.21.0/dist/axios.min.js' }); 

const data = await page.evaluate(async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
  return response.data; // <-- this is important: the whole response cannot be returned
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`page.addScriptTag`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageaddscripttagoptions) is useful in the common case, but if you have reason to do this manually in the browser context as OP is attempting, the missing piece is setting a `script.onload` function to only run code from the script (like `axios.get`) after it's loaded.

If you want to return data from the `onload` function back to Node, then you can use a promise as follows:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const result = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    const result = new Promise(resolve =>
      script.onload = () => 
        resolve(axios.get("https://httpbin.org/get"))
    );
    var url = "https://unpkg.com/axios@0.21.0/dist/axios.min.js";
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    return (await result).data;
  });
  console.log(result);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to load a local script before loading a local HTML template.

I did not want to embed the script code into the HTML template since the HTML template was already too big.

The following code and the local js file with the script code (`scriptCode.js`) were in the same directory (hence the use of `__dirname`):

```
const path = require("path");
// ...
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.addScriptTag({path: path.join(__dirname, 'scriptCode.js')})
await page.setContent(html);
```

If you have axios in a local folder, you have to point to the path where you've downloaded it.

But if you still want to download it off its CDN every time, instead of using the `path` option, [the answer provided by Vaviloff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65367516/2730233) is the perfect one.

Documentation:

- [Page.addScriptTag](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.addscripttag)
- [FrameAddScriptTagOptions interface](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.frameaddscripttagoptions)